# Python/PHP Heroku integration

Tags: python, php, heroku

Here I go again on another tangent youve been so kind to help me with.

OK...
Call a PHP script hosted on Heroku (working fine)

I would like that PHP script call a python script that sends an email. (Ive got the python part working fine and dont like my chances of rewriting it all in PHP)

So...
One heroku instance of PHP?
Second heroku instance of Python?

Three I dont bother as Im too confused.

Heroku has a web worker, which works when i call it using a scheduler, but I would like to call it on request.

Possible im sure it is, dont get it no I dont.

Any helpers??

Thanks people :)

Comment: I'm not saying you should, but even though I really dislike PHP, sending mail in PHP is as easy as mud. Perhaps launch a child process in PHP? (I'm not familiar with the works of Heroku and it might not work if you need to enter a virtual env.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Used multiple buildpacks on Heroku, one for PHP and the other Python. The PHP as a web process, which does a simple exec to the main python code. Worked a treat. Hopefully that helps someone work out a similar issue.